# Is there any way to get the installed modules without version info with pip?

Tags: pip, python-packaging, python-importlib

I tried `pip freeze`. I need it to output just the modules delimited by newlines, like `pip freeze`, except without the version number, because I am trying to create an auto upgrader, and want to do `pip install --upgrade <module>` where "<module>" is the name of the module without the version number, because as far as I know, you aren't supposed to provide the version number if you are trying to upgrade a module. For example:

```
colorama  
Flask  
pywin32
```

Instead of what `pip freeze` would do:

```
colorama==\<version>  
Flask==\<version>  
pywin32==\<version>
```

Where "<version>" is the version.
I looked through the documentation for pip commands or options of `pip freeze`, but found none. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: @wim Thanks for the quick response, could you explain how it works? I would like a Unix version as well for my Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Linux / macOS:

```bash
pip freeze | awk -F "==" '{ print $1 }'
```

The `-F` is for specifying a custom field separator, and `$1` prints the first field.

---

For Windows, where `awk` may not be available:

```bash
pip freeze | py -c "for p in __import__('sys').stdin: print(p.split('=')[0])"
```

Answer (score 3):

For a pure Python (*3.7+*) version:

```
python -c "import importlib.metadata; print('\n'.join([d.metadata['Name'] for d in importlib.metadata.distributions()]))"
```

***References***:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html